# How could I use a loop pedal with the Yamaha YDP-160 electric piano?

Tags: piano, digital-piano, looping

so I'm a pianist right, and I've been wanting to buy a loop pedal for a while but theres one problem...WILL IT WORK? so I have an electric piano  (http://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalpianos/arius_series/ydp-160/). It has a couple of 3.5mm inputs (same as most standard guitar leads that you would use to plug into an amp). I've seen many people using loop pedals but always through an amp and im curious whether or not i can plug one end of a lead into my piano and the other into the loop pedal and have it work through my pianos speakers.

Thanks for the help if anyone responds :)

Answer (score 1):

The only audio connectors on this instrument are described as being two headphone outputs, so once you've gone 'out' from the headphone socket to the looper, you won't be able to go back 'in' to the piano again to hear things through the speakers.

Options I can think of to achieve what you want are:

- connect the output of the loop pedal to an external amp and speakers
- have the instrument modified by an electronics engineer with an input so that you can g back in to the internal amp & speakers
- rather than using an audio looper, use your MIDI in/out socket with a midi looper - this should work as long as your piano can transmit and receive MIDI simultaneously.

Comment: " this should work as long as your piano can transmit and receive MIDI on the same channel simultaneously"  - except that if you use the same channel, you will probably get an endless series of loops, resulting in a horrible mess - or chaos, when the MIDI system can't handle all the data you are trying to send/receive.

Comment: @alephzero  I think that would depend on the details of how the devices   handled the messages - for example, would the piano treat its out also as a thru? but now I think about it, the requirement I isn't necessary at all. Will remove.